# Full trust c# GetProcesses() and Process.Modules throwing errors

Tags: c#, process, 64-bit, win32-process

This is minimalist code to list all running 32- and 64-bit processes on Windows, with FullTrust attributes set according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx.

```
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, SharedState = true, 
    Synchronization = true, ExternalProcessMgmt = true, SelfAffectingProcessMgmt = true)]
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var procList = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process proc in procList)
    {
        Console.Write(proc.ProcessName);
        Console.Write(" id:{0}", proc.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(" handle:{0}", proc.Handle);
        /*
        Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
            at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
            at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
            at System.Diagnostics.Process.OpenProcessHandle(Int32 access)
            at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Handle()
        */
        foreach (ProcessModule module in proc.Modules)
        /*
        Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.
           at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
           at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId)
           at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Modules()
        */
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  ", module.ModuleName, " ", module.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen in the code comments, proc.Handle and proc.Modules both throw errors on various processes. For example, svchost modules cannot be retrieved, although its handle can.

How can I get around:

- access is denied
- 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process

Perhaps System.Management could help here, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to get it to work, so I reduced this code sample back to its minimum "should work" documented behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking at *all* processes.  Including the fake "System" process, it is just a place-holder for kernel code.  Or a protected process like "audiodg", used to securely decrypt audio streams.   You *will* get an access denied exception for them, always, you'll have to catch it and move on.  Nothing to see there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @HansPassant. I'll ignore those exceptions and see how much more information I can get.